# php function script not getting called in joomla

Tags: php, function, module, joomla2.5

I have successfully created a carousel html page where the call to some php functions are getting successfully run

```
    <?php

    function getPictureType($ext) {
        if ( preg_match('/jpg|jpeg/i', $ext) ) {
            return 'jpg';
        } else if ( preg_match('/png/i', $ext) ) {
            return 'png';
        } else if ( preg_match('/gif/i', $ext) ) {
            return 'gif';
        } else {
             return '';
         }
     }



    function getPictures($id) {
        global $max_width, $max_height;
        $dir="../../images/albums/album".$id."/";
        $i = 0;
        if (is_dir($dir)) {
            if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {

                echo '<ul >';


                while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {

                if ( !is_dir($file) ) {

                    $absolute_path = $dir.'thumbs';
                     $split = explode('.', $file); 
                     $ext = $split[count($split) - 1];

                    $textfile = $dir.$split[0].'.txt';


                    if (file_exists($textfile)) {
                        $description = file_get_contents($textfile);

                     }

                    if ( ($type = getPictureType($ext)) == '' ) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    if ($i == 0) {
                    echo $i;
                    echo '<a href="'.$dir.$file.'" rel="lightbox['.$id.']" title="'.$description.'"><div class="linkicon"><i class="icon-plus-circled"></i></div></a>';     
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        echo $i;                    
                    echo '<a href="'.$dir.$file.'" rel="lightbox['.$id.']" title="'.$description.'"></a>';
                    }
                $i=$i+1;    
                }

                }

             echo '</ul>';  
         closedir($dh);
     }
  }
 }
 ?>
```

i then call them in the html

```
<div class="hovercover" style="opacity: 0;">
 <?php getPictures(1); ?>
</div>
```

this then builds the lightbox with no problems.

I have now tried to create a module using the same code in the default.php file but the `<$php getPictures(1); ?>` function is not being called and the lightbox images are not being generated. default.php looks like this

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access'); // no direct access

// get the document object
$doc =& JFactory::getDocument();

// add your stylesheet
$doc->addStyleSheet( 'modules/mod_hot_joomla_carousel/tmpl/style.css' );
// add lightbox stylesheet
$doc->addStyleSheet( 'modules/mod_hot_joomla_carousel/tmpl/lightbox.css' );

?>

<?php if ($enablejQuery!=0) { ?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8./jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php } ?>
<!-- Carousel plugin -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $mosConfig_live_site; ?>/modules/mod_hot_joomla_carousel/js/jquery.carouFredSel-6.2.1-packed.js"></script>
<!-- lightbox plugins -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $mosConfig_live_site; ?>/modules/mod_hot_joomla_carousel/js/lightbox.js"></script>


<!-- optionally include helper plugins -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $mosConfig_live_site; ?>/modules  /mod_hot_joomla_carousel/js/helper-plugins/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $mosConfig_live_site; ?>/modules/mod_hot_joomla_carousel/js/helper-plugins/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $mosConfig_live_site; ?>/modules/mod_hot_joomla_carousel/js/helper-plugins/jquery.transit.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $mosConfig_live_site; ?>/modules/mod_hot_joomla_carousel/js/helper-plugins/jquery.ba-throttle-debounce.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function() {
//  Scrolled by user interaction
jQuery('#foo2').carouFredSel({
auto: false,
    prev: '#foo2_prev',
next: '#foo2_next',
mousewheel: true,
swipe: {
    onMouse: true,
    onTouch: true
        }
});
    });
  </script>


  <?php

function getPictureType($ext) {
    if ( preg_match('/jpg|jpeg/i', $ext) ) {
        return 'jpg';
    } else if ( preg_match('/png/i', $ext) ) {
        return 'png';
    } else if ( preg_match('/gif/i', $ext) ) {
        return 'gif';
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}



function getPictures($id) {
    global $max_width, $max_height;
    $dir="../../images/albums/album".$id."/";
    $i = 0;
    if (is_dir($dir)) {
        if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {

            echo '<ul >';


            while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {

            if ( !is_dir($file) ) {

                $absolute_path = $dir.'thumbs';
                $split = explode('.', $file); 
                $ext = $split[count($split) - 1];

                $textfile = $dir.$split[0].'.txt';


                if (file_exists($textfile)) {
                    $description = file_get_contents($textfile);

                }

                if ( ($type = getPictureType($ext)) == '' ) {
                    continue;
                }

                if ($i == 0) {
                echo $i;
                echo '<a href="'.$dir.$file.'" rel="lightbox['.$id.']" title="'.$description.'"><div class="linkicon"><i class="icon-plus-circled"></i></div></a>';     
                } 
                else 
                {
                    echo $i;                    
                echo '<a href="'.$dir.$file.'" rel="lightbox['.$id.']" title="'.$description.'"></a>';
                }
            $i=$i+1;    
            }

            }

        echo '</ul>';   
    closedir($dh);
}
}
}
?>


<div class="divide30"></div>

<div class="wrapper whitebg">

            <div class="divide20"></div>
        <div class="image_carousel">
        <div class="overflowholder" style="height: 350px;">
            <ul id="foo2" style="width: 1920px; left: 0px; height: 303px;">
                <!-- Image One -->
                <li style="width: 223px;">
                    <div class="mediaholder">
                    <div class="mediaholder_innerwrap">
                        <img src="/../images/albums/album1/thumbs/thumb1.jpg" title="Image 1"/>
                    <div class="hovercover" style="opacity: 0;">
                            <?php getPictures(1); ?>            
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="detailholder">
                    <div class="divide20"></div>
                    <div class="projects-title">
                    <a href="#"><?php echo $name1; ?></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="divide15"></div>
                    <div class="projects-desc">
                    <?php echo $description1; ?>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    </li>
                <!-- Image Two -->
                <li style="width: 223px;">
                    <div class="mediaholder">
                    <div class="mediaholder_innerwrap">
                        <img src="/../images/albums/album2/thumbs/thumb2.jpg" title="Image 2"/>
                    <div class="hovercover" style="opacity: 0;">
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="detailholder">
                    <div class="divide20"></div>
                    <div class="projects-title">
                    <a href="#"><?php echo $name2; ?></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="divide15"></div>
                    <div class="projects-desc">
                    <?php echo $description2; ?>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    </li>
                <!-- Image Three -->
                <li style="width: 223px;">
                    <div class="mediaholder">
                    <div class="mediaholder_innerwrap">
                        <img src="/../images/albums/album3/thumbs/thumb3.jpg" title="Image 3"/>
                    <div class="hovercover" style="opacity: 0;">
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="detailholder">
                    <div class="divide20"></div>
                    <div class="projects-title">
                    <a href="#"><?php echo $name3; ?></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="divide15"></div>
                    <div class="projects-desc">
                    <?php echo $description3; ?>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    </li>
                <!-- Image Four -->
                <li style="width: 223px;">
                    <div class="mediaholder">
                    <div class="mediaholder_innerwrap">
                        <img src="/../images/albums/album4/thumbs/thumb4.jpg" title="Image 4"/>
                    <div class="hovercover" style="opacity: 0;">
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="detailholder">
                    <div class="divide20"></div>
                    <div class="projects-title">
                    <a href="#"><?php echo $name4; ?></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="divide15"></div>
                    <div class="projects-desc">
                    <?php echo $description4; ?>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    </li>
                <!-- Image Five -->
                <li style="width: 223px;">
                    <div class="mediaholder">
                    <div class="mediaholder_innerwrap">
                        <img src="/../images/albums/album5/thumbs/thumb5.jpg" title="Image 5"/>
                    <div class="hovercover" style="opacity: 0;">
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="detailholder">
                    <div class="divide20"></div>
                    <div class="projects-title">
                    <a href="#"><?php echo $name5; ?></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="divide15"></div>
                    <div class="projects-desc">
                    <?php echo $description5; ?>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    </li>
                <!-- Image Six -->
                <li style="width: 223px;">
                    <div class="mediaholder">
                    <div class="mediaholder_innerwrap">
                        <img src="/../images/albums/album6/thumbs/thumb6.jpg" title="Image 6"/>
                    <div class="hovercover" style="opacity: 0;">
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="detailholder">
                    <div class="divide20"></div>
                    <div class="projects-title">
                    <a href="#"><?php echo $name6; ?></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="divide15"></div>
                    <div class="projects-desc">
                    <?php echo $description6; ?>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    </li>           
            </ul>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
             <a class="prev" id="foo2_prev" href="#"><span>prev</span></a>
             <a class="next" id="foo2_next" href="#"><span>next</span></a>


    </div>
```

Why is the getPictures function not getting called, is it the position of the php functions or the way im calling them on the page

Answer (score 0):

where you defind `$mosConfig_live_site` value

try to read http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_simple_module
also try to give full url/path on your each included files

like:-  `JURI::root().'css/joomla.css';`

Comment: would this cause the php functions not to work, the rest of carousel works perfectly except where i create the lightbox through the getPictures call

Comment: check your all scripts and css included correctly and running?

Comment: yes all scripts js/css are working the only thing that isnt working are these two php functions getPictures and getPictureType. Carousel works perfectly except when attempting to call this function using '<?php getPictures(1); ?>'